# Modifying TensorFlow Neural Network connections

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am using Python 3.X along with TensorFlow 2.0 to create a toy neural network model which is as follows:

```
model = Sequential()                                                                                                         

model.add(
    Dense(
        units = 2, activation = 'relu',
        kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(),
        input_shape = (2,)
        )
    )

model.add(
    Dense(
        units = 2, activation = 'relu',
        kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
        )
    )

model.add(
    Dense(
        units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'
        )
    )
```

I now want to modify the weights/biases of the model in a layer-wise manner. The code I have come up with to change the connections of the randomly initialized weights/biases of the model is that connections having magnitude less than 0.5 should become zero, while the others should remain the same:

```
for layer in model.trainable_weights:
    layer = tf.where(tf.less(layer, 0.5), 0, layer)
```

However, this code does not change the connections as I want. What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code simply creates new tensors that have the desired values and puts them in the *Python* variable `layer`, but doesn't change the *Tensorflow* variables as you want to. You need to use the `assign` method of the `Variable` class:

```
for layer in model.trainable_weights:
    layer.assign(tf.where(tf.less(layer, 0.5), 0, layer))
```